# How can I install Ubuntu 11.04 after removing the existing Linux Mint 8?

Tags: 11.04, dual-boot, windows-xp, mint

I have both Windows XP and Linux Mint 8 on my system. I want to install Ubuntu 11.04 after removing Linux Mint.

1. Is it possible to **retain Windows** & only remove Mint?
2. Can I just format the Linux partition from the Live CD and install Ubuntu into that partition?
3. Can I dual boot into either Windows or Ubuntu from a menu without any problem if I follow this procedure?
4. Could there be any problem while dual booting? Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1 question at a time.

Answer (score 2):

```
Is it possible to retain Windows & only remove Mint?
```

Yes

```
Can I just format the Linux partition from the Live CD and  
install Ubuntu into that partition?
```

Yes

```
Can I dual boot into either Windows or Ubuntu from a menu  
without any problem if I follow this procedure?
```

I can't say without any problem...but it should just work

```
Could there be any problem while dual booting? Please advice.
```

There's always a possibility of problems, but it usually just works

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to do something very special when deleting your old Mint, you can just run the correct LiveCD from Mint and install from there which by default would only install over Mint.

Then you would be able to dual-boot just as you would normally (for instance, you could boot to either by choosing from your boot menu, as you have suggested).